# Launching app with custom applicationIdSuffix

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When attempting to run or debug a custom BuildType with a applicationIdSuffix (.debug), the app installed on the phone, but the correct activity doesn't actually launch. In fact, the activity with the original package name is launched (example: com.fobbymaster.app is launched when com.fobbymaster.app.debug should be launched).

I'm thinking that there's some configuration that needs to be modified, but I can't seem to find it.

Any ideas?

Edit: So the following error shows up when it's attempting to launch. I'm guessing that the it's getting confused with the package names..

> Installing com.fobbymaster.app
>
> DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.fobbymaster.app"
>
> pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.fobbymaster.app
>
> Success
>
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.fobbymaster.app/.activity.SimpleStartActivity }
>
> Error type 3
>
> Error: Activity class {com.fobbymaster.app/com.fobbymaster.app.activity.SimpleStartActivity} does not exist.

Comment: Are you using the standard launcher icon, or launching programmatically? Are you sure you're opening the correct version of the app? (Sounds silly, but I've made the mistake before.)

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest file? In particular, I want to see how your activities are declared there.

Comment: I'm declaring them as follows: android:name=".activity.SimpleStartActivity"

Comment: What's the `packageName` declared in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: package="com.fobbymaster.app"

Comment: Is `com.fobbymaster.app.activity.SimpleStartActivity` the correct location of your Activity in your app packages, ignoring the gradle configuration?

Comment: Also, have you done the usual clean/rebuild/sync with gradle file stuff?

Comment: Yes, and yes. I've rebuilt and cleaned a few times. And yeah, that is where the activity is. This all worked correctly before I added the applicationIdSuffix to the buildType.

Comment: I've updated the log above, and it seems like it's installing the original package name, but somehow the correct package does get installed on my phone..

Comment: I recommend adding your gradle file and manifest to the original question.. may be clues in there.

Comment: If this is a React Native application, this is a known issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8308

Comment: Are you launching in correct mode, on your lower left hand size there is a build variant chooser, are you setting that to debug before launching, also i would like to see your gradle file.

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well, since AS 3 canary. Simply hitting run again typically works. It seems to me like a bug in the preview gradle tools.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this is a bug in Cordova-Android library, or [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#extending-buildgradle) are incomplete

The prepare command reads Application Id from config.xml file, which is obviously without the `.debug` or `.release` suffix.

References:

- cordova-android: [prepare.js source](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/7.1.0/bin/templates/cordova/lib/prepare.js#L185)
- cordova-android: [github comment](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/244#issuecomment-244845815)